# Copy-Paste option not appering on long press on Edit Text inside popup windows

Tags: android, copy-paste, popupwindow

i am showing one popup window and in that there is one edit text when i long press on that edit text by default copy-paste option doesn't appear stuck with this issue is there any solution instead of creating custom coding for that copy and paste functionality.

Comment: have you got solution for this, because I am also facing same.

Answer (score -1):

you should add this code in EditText;

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: but my edittext is inside the popup window so is it working ?

Comment: Okay im waiting.

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtAddComment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.7"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:hint="Write a comment..."
            android:background="@drawable/ripplesearchbox" />

Comment: its not working when i click on edit text keyboard also stop to popup after add textIsSelectedable

Comment: please try this option;
android:cursorVisible="true"

Comment: not working :( keyboard also not poped up when click on edittext

Comment: delete textisselecteadable option;
and add this funciton: android:longClickable="false"

Comment: ya now key board and curson both showing but as per my requirement on long press copy and paste option not showing :(

Comment: Okay, you can add this line on java code.

isSuggestionsEnabled and canPaste option in EditText.

Comment: i have add this but still not getting that option ......its should be work on edit text which is in activity xml file but in my case my edit text is in already popup window and we are trying to show one more popup of paste and copy option on it so is it possible ...